# How to represent Golang struct with variable field names

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling

If this has been answered somewhere else let me know but I couldn't find anything.

Basically, let's say we have the following JSON. `string-id-001` can be an arbitrary string. We want to unmarshal it into a struct, and be able to access the unique id's.

```
{"list":{"string-id-001":{"id":"blah","name":"cool"},"string-id-002":{"id":"yas","name":"rad"}}}
```

Golang as far as I can tell would require something like below which doesn't work if the `keyhere` value is constantly changing. Eg if it's an ID

```
type Foo struct {
    List struct {
        StringID001 struct {
            ID   string `json:"id"`
            Name string `json:"name"`
        } `json:"string-id-001"`
        StringID002 struct {
            ID   string `json:"id"`
            Name string `json:"name"`
        } `json:"string-id-002"`
    } `json:"list"`
}
```

I've seen a similar issue in another project (which I solved with interfaces rather than structs), and I'm wondering if there's a nicer solution. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

```golang
type payLoad struct {
     ID   string `json:"id"`
     Name string `json:"name"`
}

type Foo struct {
    List map[string]payLoad `json:"list"`
}
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation?